# How does SymPy respond when solving for many variables?

Tags: python, sympy, system, equation

I am trying to produce a counterexample for a system of equations/inequalities. Essentially I want to find an input (which is represented by an array of variables called A) that cannot produce a valid output (which is represented by an array of variables called B). I know that sympy finds solutions given a system of equations, so I am wondering if it is possible to direct it to find a valid A such that there is no valid B? Essentially A and B are both used in the equations so they are both variables used in the same way as far as sympy is concerned, but with regards to my original problem I want to find a solution to one set of variables that breaks the system basically, one that produces no solution to the other set.

I was thinking of negating/flipping some of the equations/inequalities, but this can only help me find an input that produces one bad output, whereas I want an input that produces all bad outputs. I don't really know where to go from here as this is my first time using SymPy.

Comment: The question is too vague for anyone to be able to offer any meaningful help.

Comment: People often complain about `sympy` taking for ever to find a solution.  Wether that means no solution is possible, or it's just too difficult or big, is not clear